# Python Memory not reclaimed after GC

Tags: python, macos, garbage-collection, psutil, del

Python in Mac: I was trying to understand `gc.collect()` and i wrote this code.
My expectation is that value of `diff` should be zero, but it isn't.

```
import gc
import numpy as np
import psutil

def create_and_destory():
    np.random.randn(10000)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gc.collect()
    start_process = psutil.Process().memory_info().rss
    create_and_destory()
    gc.collect()
    end_process = psutil.Process().memory_info().rss
    diff = end_process - start_process
    print('diff value is: {}'.format(diff))
```

> diff value is 36864

Couldn't quite get the reason for this behavior even after forceful trigger of garbage collection.
PS:
**This returns a non-zero value only in MAC. In linux distros am getting a zero!**

Comment: I get `diff value is 0` ,

Comment: I just tried, running it in a online interpreter - [link](https://replit.com/@stonelazy/MotherlyRoughMethod#main.py). Am getting a non-zero value there as well ?!

Comment: I just noticed this, this returns some non-zero value only if run in Mac. In Linux distro it returns 0.